# How to load zmm1 with "1" (AVX-512)

Tags: assembly, avx512

I need to fill zmm1 with "1" to be able quickly fill large data field in a memory in a loop. How to set zmm1 by "1" like mov rax, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh in Intel assembly? I don't have any experience with {k1}{z} parameters.

See code below.

```
PCMPEQD zmm1, zmm1
```

I got an error code "invalid instruction operands"

Answer (score 2):

clang++ and g++ use `vpternlogd zmm0, zmm0, zmm0, 255`. I found this using https://godbolt.org and https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide

Comment: Yup, this is generally the best choice for ZMM regs.  It does have a false dependency on the old value, though, so use with care.  Inside a loop you might want `vmovdqa64` to copy an existing register, instead of re-generating an all-ones vector, because that doesn't need an ALU execution unit on Skylake-family CPUs.

Comment: Unfortunately I noticed that my CPU 7500u can handle 256 bits only:

> AVX supported
AVX2 supported
AVX512CD not supported
AVX512ER not supported
AVX512F not supported
AVX512PF not supported

How to modify vpternlogd zmm0, zmm0, zmm0, 255 for AVX2 i.e. ymm0 register?