# How to get a constant (integer) value into all 8 slots of an avx _m256 register most efficiently

Tags: x86, bit-manipulation, x86-64, sse, avx

I have an integer value of -1  and want to load it as fast as possible into all 8 slots of a _m256 register like ymm0.

I didnt find an assembly instruction.
MASM doesnt accept

```
vmovaps    ymm1, 0FFFFFFFFh         ; -1
```

When using intrinsics  like

```
// get constant values into sse register    
    __m256  tmp     = _mm256_set1_ps(rp->xc);
```

The generated code in visual studio looks like:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [rp]  
vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rax+34h]  
vshufps     xmm0,xmm0,xmm0,0  
vinsertf128 ymm0,ymm0,xmm0,1  
vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp+7C0h],ymm0  
vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp+7C0h]  
vmovups     ymmword ptr [tmp],ymm0
```

This is a little long for a rather simple thing that happens
all the time. I still hope there is a direct instruction that does this. I am looking for assembler (using intrinsics just to see what the compiler does).

I am aware that i must somehow specify that all 8 slots in the _m256 get the same value.

So far my only idea is to pass the constant (-1) in rdx.
Then load rdx into ymm1 and then do some shuffling.
I just think i do something wrong , because, again loading a constant value (or a single float/int) to all slots of a avx register should be a very common task. So i cant believe that there is no dedicated instruction for this.

Comment: Why can't you compare a register for equality with itself? That's just one instruction.

Comment: That `vmovss/vshufps/vinsertf128` is strange (why not `vbroadcastss`?) but then those redundant `vmovups` later are a hint that it was compiled at a low optimization level

Comment: vbroadcastss looks interesting. I have an int, so vbroadcasti32x2 looks better. Unluckily there is no vbroadcasti32x1.  I would then duplicate the -1 on the C++ side and pass a pointer to it the assembler routine, so vbroadcasti32x2  can read it from "memory".

Comment: The type doesn't really matter, it's just data movement, there is also an `vpbroadcastd` though (AVX2)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085059/what-are-the-best-instruction-sequences-to-generate-vector-constants-on-the-fly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57565473/how-to-load-zmm1-with-1-avx-512 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105164/set-all-bits-in-cpu-register-to-1-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

When using intrinsics, you should really just stick with `_mm256_set1_epi32(-1)` (use `_mm256_castsi256_ps` if you want a `__m256` instead of a `__m256i`). And make sure to compile with optimizations enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/zQ9nZZ

Whether it is better to load the constant from memory or use a `vcmptrueps` (as clang is doing, after clearing the register with `vxorps` to avoid false dependencies) likely depends on the context as well as the target architecture (for gcc and clang you should always compile with `-march=native` if you know your target architecture).

Comment: AVX1 `vcmptrueps` is *only* useful when AVX2 isn't available (for dependency-breaking special-cased `vpcmpeqd same,same`).  Although on Intel CPUs, "bypass delay" extra latency applies forever, even when the result of a SIMD-integer insn has been "cold" for ages it still increases the latency of a `vmulps` using it as an input.  Fortunately rarely a problem for `set1(-1)` because that's a NaN.